# SQL FOREIGN KEY's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How do prevent a table with 2 FOREIGN key's from having repeated rows with the same value.

[image]

Thks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a unique index or constraint:

```
alter table example
    add constraint unq_example_fk1_fk2 unique (fk1, fk2);
```

A unique constraint and unique index do essentially the same thing.  So, you can also do:

```
create unique index unq_example_fk_fk on example(fk1, fk2);
```

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Indexes can be named, of course.  However, I don't  think the index name appears in the error message.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Thank you for that info.  I modified the answer.